# How do I place contextMenu under button in this code?

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I would like to get buttons like in AX, where some buttons only open a menu with more menu items underneath. I have found the code below and it works fine. But when I left-click on the button, it shows the context menu where the mouse pointer is. When I right-click on the button, it shows the context menu exactly under the button nicely. I would like the left-click to work like the right-click.

The problem is that `ContextMenuService.Placement="Bottom"` is only working when I right-click.

```
<Button Name="MainButton" Content="Button with ContextMenu" Width="150" Height="30" ContextMenuService.Placement="Bottom">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="MainContextMenu" PlacementRectangle="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}">
            <MenuItem Header="Do A" />
            <MenuItem Header="Do B" />
            <MenuItem Header="Do C" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>

    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger SourceName="MainButton" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MainContextMenu" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContextMenu.IsOpen)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <system:Boolean>True</system:Boolean>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: You could just use a `MenuItem` instead of the `Button`. From what you wrote it seems like you need exactly what the `MenuItem` control does and none of what a `Button` control does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `Storyboard` for setting a single property value is pretty odd. This works, but looks somewhat ugly.

But this is also the reason why your `ContextMenuService.Placement="Bottom"` setting doesn't work: you just don't invoke the `ContextMenuService` for opening the context menu via the `Storyboard`, so the `PlacementTarget` won't be set to your button.

I'd suggest you to create a simple attached property and re-use it in your views:

```
static class ContextMenuTools
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OpenOnLeftClickProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "OpenOnLeftClick", 
            typeof(bool), 
            typeof(ContextMenuTools),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, OpenOnLeftClickChanged));

    public static void SetOpenOnLeftClick(UIElement element, bool value)
        => element.SetValue(OpenOnLeftClickProperty, value);

    public static bool GetOpenOnLeftClick(UIElement element)
        => (bool)element.GetValue(OpenOnLeftClickProperty);

    private static void OpenOnLeftClickChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is IInputElement element && (bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            element.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += ElementOnMouseLeftButtonDown;
        }
    }

    private static void ElementOnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is UIElement element
            && ContextMenuService.GetContextMenu(element) is ContextMenu contextMenu)
        {
            contextMenu.Placement = ContextMenuService.GetPlacement(element);
            contextMenu.PlacementTarget = element;
            contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage might look like this:

```
<Button Content="Button with ContextMenu" ContextMenuService.Placement="Bottom"
    yourNS:ContextMenuTools.OpenOnLeftClick="True">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="MainContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Do A" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Note the `yourNS` namespace - this is a XAML namespace mapped to the CLR namespace where the attached property class `ContextMenuTools` is located, e.g.:

```
xmlns:yourNS="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
```

You could also use this attached property on any WPF control implementing `IInputElement`, not only on buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick instead of using a `Button`

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Options">
        <MenuItem Header="Do A"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Do B"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Do C"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```